# Proof regarding the limits of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{x_n\}_n$ and $\{y_n\}_n$ be positive sequences. Having trouble proving the following:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ exists and is nonzero, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{x_n}$ exists and is nonzero.

I have tried using the formal definition of a limit but it hasn't really gotten me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: can you do the special case where $y_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: @GregMartin not to clear on what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_n := \frac{x_n}{y_n}$, so $z_n \to L \neq 0$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, let $N_1$ be large enough so that $n \geq N_1 \implies |z_n - L| < \epsilon$. Furthermore, let $N_2$ be large enough so that $n \geq N_2 \implies |z_n| > \frac{L}{2}$. Then, for $n \geq \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, we have that:
$$
\left|\frac{1}{z_n} - \frac{1}{L}\right| = \left|\frac{z_n - L}{z_nL}\right| < \frac{2\epsilon}{L^2}
$$
So $\frac{1}{z_n} \to \frac{1}{L}$.